# What's the purpose of trailing white lines in Python docstrings?

Tags: python, standards, docstring

I've seen a trailing white line at the end of Python docstrings (like [in `Numpy` docstrings](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py#L104-#L106) and [in Google style docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html), and I recall having read somewhere that this was suggested.

That said, they seem to be ignored in docstring converters, such as [in `Napolean`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/napoleon/docstring.py#L766-#L784) and in the example routine [in the PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#handling-docstring-indentation) docs.

What is the purpose for adding a trailing white line in Python docstrings? Is it purely for legibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It used to be recommended by PEP257, so that editor paragraph-wrapping commands could be used conveniently.  But that recommendation was removed three years ago: https://github.com/python/peps/commit/ab85e78f9b2a06c8c2b7866e0577787f21346fd5

Comment: Crazy fast answer and great with the commit link!